# Using transistors to boost MOSFET gate voltage alternatives

Tags: cmos, optimization

I'm working with a micro controller based on CMOS logic. So I want to drive a load that is connected to the P-MOSFET low side.

To make sure that the gate is fully saturated, I want to boost the 5 V to 12 V (that is supplied by the power supply). For that, I am going to use this kind of scheme (you can of course propose cheaper alternatives to this scheme):

[image: NPN transistor boosting voltage for P-MOSFET gate saturation]

1n represents the load, 0V MPU pin state.

Here´s the problem. Because I need to boost at least 12 MOSFET gates, does there exist some IC that can take separate signal inputs and boost the 5 V CMOS logic based signal to 12 V signal. At the moment it seems that the transistor solution is the cheapest but will require a lot of soldering which I don't like.

Comment: saturated is a bipolar transistor term for 'fully on', saturated means the linear region in a FET. Just so you don;t confuse people with using the wrong terms.

Comment: Yes, Gate Drivers exist. But they'll have more pins than a transistor so you won't save much soldering.

Comment: You can use e.g. DM7417N which can handle 15V, but you then still need the resistor on the gate side. Anyway make it <= 10k. Other options: ULN2003, TBD62503A

Comment: _"but will require a lot of soldering which I don t like."_ Get practicing. It's a required skill as an EE.

Comment: The uln2003 just begs to be used for this kind of project, if you can find it

Comment: there are ICs (transistor arrays) with many transistors in one package, making it easy to scale your above circuit.

Comment: @Lorenzo ULN is an old school hammer driver. This is not a hammer. It's not even a nail.  CMOS 50 Ohms, transistor current gain 100 typ. R_series limits the current. ANY NPN will do. 1 NPN to all 10 FETs.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 One for all ten FETs, *if* they're all meant to be driven by the same input signal and not separate switching signals.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 it's not an hammer but it's less than 10 cents and it has 7 drivers in the package. TI itself recommend it as the cheapest level translator. *Unless* to OP has some really underpowered GPIOs that cannot put out the current to drive it; AFAIK they don't do MOSFET arrays that cheap

Comment: Oliver, you failed. To understand my advice

Answer (score 3):

Gate drivers do what you want, but they usually do not have more than one or two channels.

Logic voltage translators that can handle 12 V do exist in the 4000B series. Devices like the [CD40109B](https://www.ti.com/product/CD40109B)/​[CD4504B](https://www.ti.com/product/CD4504B)/​[HEF4104B](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/asynchronous-interface-logic/voltage-translators-level-shifters/series/HEF4104B.html)/​[MC14504B](https://www.onsemi.com/products/timing-logic-memory/standard-logic/level-translators/mc14504b) have four or six channels.

Comment: This was exatly the answer I was looking for. Forgot the termin.

Comment: They are high resistance though like 1k to 3k

Answer (score 0):

You cannot design any switch without specs for I and load impedance. If it is a capacitive load on startup, then ESR limits the current with RdsOn and USB current limit.

You could use just a low-side driver with RdsOn that is 1% or less than your equivalent load but have ground shift from I*RdsOn which is ok if you use that output as your signal ground for analysis. Then you just need a 1V logic level Nch FET with low RdsOn driven from any logic level.

Otherwise, if your Pch high-side driver is in place and works, ANY NPN 500 mA transistor or more will work with > 20 mA base current from V drop on the base resistor.

All Gates can be tied together.  Consider if each FET is 3nF for Ciss.
and NPN has a linear gain of 100 with 5V logic.  for Ib=20 mA Vb =0.7 Rb=235 +/-10%  , Ic= limited by the current in linear range .

### 1Apk on collector into 30 nF means dV/dt= Ic/ C= 1.5 us.  A PN2222A easily does this .

- then 10:1 in saturation where the FET has already switched on so current gain does  not matter.
- Rce of transistor which is 0.5 to 1 ohm for a PN2222A.

  - thus turn on time is 1 Ohm * 30 nF = 30 nanosecond rise time if that were the case, but it is not.

What's the problem?  **Keep leads wide and short as parasitic inductance will resonate with L/W wire length/width ratio.** Use braid if possible for Vgs signals or coax or twisted pairs. There is NO NEED TO  USE A DARLINGTON TO TURN ON !) FETS with a PN2222A from CMOS with 240  Ohms from 5V or 180 ohms from 3.3V.

- consider skinny wires to Gate 10 cm at 10 nH/cm or 100 nH with 30 nF from 10 FETs  LC=

need proof ? just ask.

But, this still begs the question, where are your expectations. Turn On-time, Turn off time. Ciss of FET or at least P/N.

*Gimme the SPECS  ma'am and nuttin but the SPECs.*

Comment: The ULN28xx series will work nicely and are much easier to find. I use the ULN2803 a lot.

Comment: @Gil A Darlington is overkill and slower than . "Any" NPN which will drive a Pch FET (3nF) with a CMOS small base resistor. ANY simall signal or switching transistor not RF and switch as fast as the FET will switch for turn ON. Turn off depends on Pullup R. Like < 1k to 10k. With 10 mA base current and up to 500 mA   Q charge peak is possible . then 0 uA.

Comment: The ULN2803 is inexpensive, available, It does not need a base resistor, speed was never mentioned and it has the drive to turn the FET on. Once it is on the sat voltage is about 1.1 volts. Consider the time to add 8 resistors and 8 transistors.

Comment: YES @Gil I see even Digikey has gone to marketplace for most of their transistors, some they have millions available on marketplace and 100k inhouse, but none for https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/transistors-bipolar-bjt-arrays/277?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKoBkByYAcAGAzCAugXyA  yet , small shops or other distis will have it

Comment: @Gil not so sure about the availability of the ULNs. Had serious provisioning issues in the last few months